# Can we validate USDZ model using any Python tool?

Tags: python, zsh, arkit, realitykit, usdz

I have generated USDZ file using command line tool usdzconvert. I need a tool to verify that USDZ generated properly or not. Any python commandline tool can do USDZ file validation?

Please find [this](https://file.io/7o7ZmcnTjjV9) USDZ file which work properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have [USDZ Tools](https://developer.apple.com/augmented-reality/tools/) installed, you may check your USDZ model with the following command in Terminal app:

```
usdchecker /Users/swift/model.usdz --arkit
```

By this token, this command is already included in `usdzconvert` script.

Also, you can use:

```
usdARKitChecker /Users/swift/model.usdz
```

that is a Python script validating existing USDZ file. At the moment it consists of three parts:

- `usdchecker` validation
- `mesh attribute` validation
- `UsdPreviewSurface material` validation